# radio button value in php

Tags: php, post, radio-button

I'm trying to make a simple survey in php

I have a set of radio buttons on a page called sja.php that sends its to sjamail.php page

the problem is that when I go to get

```
$answer = $_POST['ans'];
```

I can't seen to do anything like

```
echo "$answer";
```

but if I were to throw some logic at it

```
like

    if ($answer == "ans1") {

        echo 'Correct';
    }

   else {

       echo 'Incorrect';
    }
```

It will display correct or incorrect (edit: The if/else works correctly and will display the correct answer )

so why is it I can't access the value of the radio button "ans" as a string?

http://www.markonsolutions.com/sja.php

`print_r($_POST);` will return `Array ( [ans] => )`

Comment: I'm not following - the code with the if/else in it actually works? That is, it doesn't always display "Incorrect"?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the page?

Comment: Does `print_r($_POST)` return `Array ( [ans] => )` if you select some of the items and then submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page works correctly if you select any of the first 4 radio buttons (ans1/2/3/4). But the rest of the radio buttons next to all those images have blank values, which would explain why your posted value is empty if you selected any of those to test with.

Comment: YOU ARE THE WINNAR!!!! the script in the first page was using the wrong variable for the value field (when creating the radio buttons).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the value is something other than text.

Try

```
var_dump($answer);
```

or

```
print_r($answer, TRUE);
```

Comment: var_dump($answer);  displays "NULL"

Comment: print_r($answer, TRUE); doesn't display anything

Comment: print_r($_POST); prints "Array ( [ans] => ) "

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the field in HTML has...

```
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans1" />
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans2" />
```

Also make sure your form method is POST

Comment: confirmed POST and yes each value is different

Comment: I just checked your form. Look like the output is correct. I clicked on 4 and submit and the output confirmed my selection. Try a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$answer = (string)$_POST["ans"];
echo $answer;
```

You must convert `$_POST["ans"]` to string.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the following:

```
     <input name="03 - Gender" type="radio" value="Masculino"/>Male<br/>
     <input name="03 - Gender" type="radio" value="Femenino" required="required"/>Female <br/>
     <input type="hidden" name="03 - Gender" value=""/>
```

but when I removed the third input line (the hidden one) the problem desapeared.