# Getting PHP to display radio button information

Tags: php, radio-button

I would like to have several radio button to display information for a dynamic webpage. I have (in PHP):

```
echo '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Dynamic PHP </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="dynamic.php" method="get">
                <input type="radio" name="dynamic" value="home" checked> Home </br>
                <input type="radio" name="dynamic" value="site1"> Site 1 </br>
                <input type="radio" name="dynamic" value="site2"> Site 2
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
';

if (isset($_GET["home"])){
    echo "Home";
}
if (isset($_GET["site1"])){
    echo "Site 1";
}
if (isset($_GET["site2"])){
    echo "Site 2";
}
```

I don't get any errors, but nothing happens either. Thanks a lot.

Edit: This is like what I'm asking: [radio button value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580614/radio-button-value-in-php)

Comment: "Home", "Site 1", or "Site 2" doesn't appear when the buttons are pushed.

Comment: @DainisAbols What do you mean "works fine"? like does the code work for you?

Comment: Are you submitting this form to the same page, and then wanting to "check" the one that was selected?

Comment: yes, I want which ever radio button that is checked to display a certain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP accesses form variables through their "name" attribute, not their "value" attribute.  In order to retrieve the value of the selected radio button, you would use `$_GET['dynamic']` and not `$_GET['home']` or `$_GET['site1']` or `$_GET['site2']`.

So assuming this page is called dynamic.php, your code to echo the selected one would be:

```
if(!empty($_GET['dynamic'])){

    echo $_GET['dynamic'];

}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: In order to echo the selected option:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_GET['dynamic'])){
      $selected = $_GET['dynamic'];
}
else{
      //if no option was selected, set home as default
      $selected = 'home';
}
?>

<form action="dynamic.php" method="get">
         <input type="radio" name="dynamic" value="home"  /> Home <?php echo ($selected == 'home' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
         <input type="radio" name="dynamic" value="site1" /> Site 1 <?php echo ($selected == 'site1' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
         <input type="radio" name="dynamic" value="site2" /> Site 2 <?php echo ($selected == 'site2' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
</form>
```

Comment: hm. I'm trying to do that but nothing is displayed besides the three radio buttons

Comment: Oh, well what exactly are you trying to display next to the buttons?  Say I chose "home", what would you like it to say?

Comment: Changed the above code to display something next to the selected option.  Try that.

Comment: Thanks. Where should I put this? And shouldn't 'home' be "home"?

Comment: and what does the "?" do inside the `($selected == "home" ? echo "This was selected!' ? " ")`

Comment: Sorry, wrote it incorrectly.  It's the shorthand for if/else statement.  (if_this ? then_this : else_this)    Second "?" should be a ":".  I fixed it in the code above.

Comment: PHP reads apostrophes and quotes as nearly the same.  Both create strings, so that `echo "cat";` and `echo 'cat';` would produce the same results.  They are mostly interchangeable.  All you need to do is place what you want written in place of the `echo 'This was selected!'` section of each statement.

Comment: Thanks for that. Also, it gives me a notice saying the t-echo was unexpected. Do you have any say on this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13955/discussion-between-chase-yuan-and-the-red-baron)

Answer (score 5):

because your radiobuttons have name attribute set to "dynamic", I guess you have to try this:

```
if(isset($_GET["dynamic"])) {
    // do something here
    echo $_GET["dynamic"];
}
```

Comment: Hm. Strange. It doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: it is strange... I can't check it right now, but this should work

Comment: I have three radio buttons. Should I set ($_GET["dynamic"]) for all the radio buttons? I don't think that will work because it will set all the radio buttons to display the same thing when they are set to "dynamic". Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: if $_GET["dynamic"] is set, this means that any of that buttons is selected, the value of the selected one is IN the $_GET["dynamic"]

Comment: I've updated your answer to display the checked radio button.

Comment: I swear I had it working earlier today. I know it was, so it is possible.

Comment: of course it is possible but I don't understand why it doesn't work